# meaning of commands in solus

Tags: package-management, solus

I am using the Solus operating system. While compiling, I came across a problem, so I searched internet to find the solution.  I found the following command as a solution to my problem:

```
sudo eopkg it -c system.devel
```

I need to know the meaning of this command and what it actually does.

Comment: It will install development tools like compiler, linker, make and such [according to this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37528215/201318). See also the [Solus Wiki](https://wiki.solus-project.com/Building_packages)

Answer (score 0):

As per [kba's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/298190/meaning-of-commands-in-solus#comment524110_298190), it will:

> install development tools like compiler, linker, make and such

as referenced in this Stack Overflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37528215/4957508

The answer there says:

> Please note that Solus is not based on Ubuntu, rather, it is built from scratch. Thus Ubuntu repos and package names are not applicable here.
>
> The functional equivalent to "build-essential" on Solus is the system.devel component. To install it, issue the following command in your terminal:
>
> ```
>     sudo eopkg it -c system.devel
> ```

The answer and comments also point to the [Solus Package Management wiki](https://wiki.solus-project.com/Package_Management).

The wiki describes the `it` parameter as being a shortcut for the `install` command, which will "Install a specified package". I could not find any online documentation for the `-c` flag.